# Reshaping with base::reshape results in fewer rows with warning

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe as below

```
parklotrate_df <- data.frame( spaceNum=c(1,1,23,23,24,24,25,25,24,24), type=c("EMP", "EMP", "VIP", "VIP", "VIP", "VIP","RESV", "RESV", "VIP", "VIP"), parkinout=c("IN","OUT", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT", "IN", "OUT"), time=c("2015/9/4 19:43", "2015/9/4 21:16", "2015/9/4 19:39","2015/9/4 21:11","2015/9/3 08:00","2015/9/3 19:40","2015/9/3 23:00", "2015/9/4 19:51","2015/9/3 21:01","2015/9/3 22:01"))

> parklotrate_df
   spaceNum type parkinout           time
1         1  EMP        IN 2015/9/4 19:43
2         1  EMP       OUT 2015/9/4 21:16
3        23  VIP        IN 2015/9/4 19:39
4        23  VIP       OUT 2015/9/4 21:11
5        24  VIP        IN 2015/9/3 08:00
6        24  VIP       OUT 2015/9/3 19:40
7        25 RESV        IN 2015/9/3 23:00
8        25 RESV       OUT 2015/9/4 19:51
9        24  VIP        IN 2015/9/3 21:01
10       24  VIP       OUT 2015/9/3 22:01
```

I reshape the dataframe to wide format with below command,
and I get some warning message.

```
reshape(parklotrate_df, idvar=c("spaceNum","type"), timevar="parkinout", direction="wide")
  spaceNum type        time.IN       time.OUT
1        1  EMP 2015/9/4 19:43 2015/9/4 21:16
3       23  VIP 2015/9/4 19:39 2015/9/4 21:11
5       24  VIP 2015/9/3 08:00 2015/9/3 19:40
7       25 RESV 2015/9/3 23:00 2015/9/4 19:51
Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for parkinout=IN: first taken
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for parkinout=OUT: first taken
>
```

The output is missing record 9,10 for VIP24 IN time 2015/9/3 21:01 OUT 2015/09/03 22:01

I would expect to get

```
      spaceNum type        time.IN       time.OUT
1        1  EMP 2015/9/4 19:43 2015/9/4 21:16
3       23  VIP 2015/9/4 19:39 2015/9/4 21:11
5       24  VIP 2015/9/3 08:00 2015/9/3 19:40
7       25 RESV 2015/9/3 23:00 2015/9/4 19:51
9       24  VIP 2015/9/3 21:01 2015/9/3 22:01
```

What command I can do to obtain this result?

Comment: If you make the `spaceNum` column unique in terms of pairs it will be fine

Comment: As @AkhilNair notes, this works: `reshape(parklotrate_df[1:8,], idvar=c("spaceNum","type"), timevar="parkinout", direction="wide")`. You do not have the appropriate uniquenesses enforced.

Comment: yes, I observed that, somehow, my data is real live parking data that might occurs a lot out duplicate spaceNum IN/OUT records, I have try to add a "ID" field so that "ID"+"SpaceNum"+"type" will unique, but the result seem not good and need additional handle. I am not sure if adding "ID" is a correct way to resolve my problem, please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, taking into account the comments and the edit to OP's question, this should work.

```
df <- with(parklotrate_df,parklotrate_df[order(spaceNum,time),])
df <- df[-4,]   # remove one of the "OUT" for the sake of the demo...
df$id <- cumsum(df$parkinout=="IN")
reshape(df, idvar=c("id","spaceNum","type"), timevar="parkinout", direction="wide")[,-3]
#   spaceNum type        time.IN       time.OUT
# 1        1  EMP 2015/9/4 19:43 2015/9/4 21:16
# 3       23  VIP 2015/9/4 19:39           <NA>
# 5       24  VIP 2015/9/3 08:00 2015/9/3 19:40
# 9       24  VIP 2015/9/3 21:01 2015/9/3 22:01
# 7       25 RESV 2015/9/3 23:00 2015/9/4 19:51
```

Comment: @jihoward, yes, similar that, somehow,  the real data might not order in pairs and also might not  have an "OUT" for every "IN" under some time period, still thinking is there is good solutions for that. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, your data does not make sense. Presumably, a space cannot be occupied by more than one car(?) at one time. But that is what you have happening for space 24: someone enters at 08:00 on 9/3 and leaves the next day (19:40 on 9/4). While they are occupying that space, someone else enters at 21:01 on 9/3 and leaves an hour later. How is this possible?

Comment: @jihoward, you are correct;i have typo in the data on record 6 for vip24 leave time should be 9/3 19:40 instead of 9/4 19:40, so the data will be pairs in most of the case, except the case have in without out during capture time that cars not exit, thinking if your sol will work under such case.

Comment: @jihoward, thanks for point out the incorrect data, I have modified original post so that fit real case, btw, does that mean I sort my data first then your sol will work?

Comment: See my edits. Note I removed one of the "OUT" rows to simulate the situation you describe above.

Comment: @jihoward, Thank you very much~ your solutions work perfectly!